# python Буквы по алфавиту

Tags: python

Есть код, нужно как то создать код который будет равен букве по алфавиту(кириллица)

```
a = str(input('Введите Фамилию: '))
for i in range(len(a)):
    print ('Буква: {}, Код: {}, Шифрограмма: {}'.format(a[i], i, i**5 % 91))

print (a)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: перечитайте еще раз что вы написали и переформилируйте вопрос

Comment: если есть код, то зачем его создавать?

Comment: Да ошибся, код который не код программы и не номер буквы по порядку в строке, а код - номер буквы по алфавиту. A - 1 Б - 2 и тд

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот получше, со спрашиваемым ключом:

```
a = list(input('Введите Фамилию --> ').lower())
alph = list("абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя")
key=int(input('Введите ключ шифрования --> '))
for i in range(len(a)):
    f=a[i]
    fi=alph.index(f)
    fi=alph[fi+key]
    a[i]=fi
print("Зашифрованная фамилия: "+''.join(a))
```

***Строк столько же.***

Можно сделать так, чтобы он не выдавал ошибку, например, при введении ключа `a`:

```
while True:
    try:
        a = list(input('Введите Фамилию --> ').lower())
        alph = list("абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя")
        key=int(input('Введите ключ шифрования --> '))
        for i in range(len(a)):
            f=a[i]
            fi=alph.index(f)
            fi=alph[fi+key]
            a[i]=fi
        print("Зашифрованная фамилия: "+''.join(a))
        break
    except:
        print("ERROR: вы ввели неправильное значение. Программа перезапущена")
```

***Добавились 4 строки.***

**Кстати, зачем вы делали `str(input(...))`? Ведь значение `input` уже вводится в *строковом типе***

Comment: Проверил программу, если ввожу ключ i**5 % 91 вылезает ошибка

Comment: вводите *числовое* значение

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так:

```
a = str(input('Введите Фамилию: '))
a = a.lower()
alph = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"
name = {}
for i in a:
    name.update({i:alph.find(i)+1})
for letter, key in name.items():
   print ('Буква: {}, Код: {}, Шифрограмма: {}'.format(letter, key, key**5 % 91))
print (a)
```

Comment: Вам нужна зашифрованная фамилия?

Comment: Да, но я уже сделал, просто интересно как можно оптимизировать код

Comment: _просто интересно как можно оптимизировать код_, задать новый вопрос, на ответ никто не ответит.

Comment: @0xdb Я ответил